# 16.04 lts is taking a long time to boot and even longer to shut down

Tags: boot, shutdown

I am having troubles with boot time and also shut down time.  I spotted one answer to this question, tried it out but cannot figure what it all means.  I copied the readout and will past it here.

```
rod@rod:~$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 48.504s apt-daily.service
     42.739s docker.service
     15.522s nmbd.service
     14.555s samba-ad-dc.service
     12.347s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      9.720s ModemManager.service
      8.918s apache2.service
      7.186s dev-sdb1.device
      6.572s accounts-daemon.service
      6.229s snapd.service
      6.025s libvirt-bin.service
      5.542s apport.service
      5.317s networking.service
      5.151s ondemand.service
      5.063s systemd-logind.service
      5.041s speech-dispatcher.service
      5.000s cgroupfs-mount.service
      4.996s systemd-user-sessions.service
      3.974s NetworkManager.service
      3.905s systemd-udev-settle.service
      3.168s lightdm.service
      2.861s gpu-manager.service
      2.840s qemu-kvm.service
```

lines 1-23

Comment: yeah, ubuntu is gaining more and more bloat

Comment: Have you tried running sudo apt-get -f install


My fresh install was booting and shutting down slow also and after I did this it seemed to fix alot of different problems I was having.

Comment: Your system appears to be quite slow as is clear from the output. Most of time this issue is subjective means it depends on your hardware and the way in which software have been installed.